# Attaching Certificate to CloudDistribution with ARN fails with InvalidViewerCertificate

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to create a CloudFront Distribution using the AWS SDK under NodeJS and when I set the ARN of the cert like so

```
ViewerCertificate: {
    ACMCertificateArn: cert_arn,
    CertificateSource: 'acm',
    CloudFrontDefaultCertificate: false,
    MinimumProtocolVersion: 'TLSv1.1_2016',
    SSLSupportMethod: 'sni-only'
}
```

And then call...

```
cloudfront.createDistribution()
```

I get...

`InvalidViewerCertificate: The specified SSL certificate doesn't exist, isn't in us-east-1 region, isn't valid, or doesn't include a valid certificate chain`

When I create the cert I:

- set the right record for verification in Route 53
- I wait until the cert is validated

Only then I try to create a Distribution, which fails. Funny thing, If I

- hardcode a Cert ARN that I already have,
- wait for the Distribution finish doing its business
- Manually switch with the cert that I created with the steps described above, it works without a problem. I literally select it from the drop down menu and done.

What am I missing here?

Comment: As per the document, CertificateSource it has been deprecated, not sure but that could be the issue.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFront.html

Comment: How exactly does *hardcode a Cert ARN that I already have* differ from what you are doing here?

Comment: Exactly, there is no different, the value returned from AWS, and me copy and pasting an ARN from the AWS Console is the exact same format. Thus this questions :) I have to yet test the suggestion of Sudo.

Comment: @sudo you were right, good catch, and thank you for your time.

Comment: @sudo if you'd like to write an official answer I will accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CertificateSource filed has been [deprecated](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFront.html) and instead we have to use one of the following:

ViewerCertificate$ACMCertificateArn
ViewerCertificate$IAMCertificateId
ViewerCertificate$CloudFrontDefaultCertificate